# What is StreamBody, why I can't consum it from Delphi client side?

Tags: wcf, delphi, stream

I am build a WCF service return Documents(Docx/Doc, PDF, Xls) to client side.

In current implementation, the WCF service return the output document as `Stream` to client side.

Without much effort, I can consume it on a .Net client application by copy the returned `Stream`to a `FileStream` and save it to local file system. And I also managed to build a Delphi client side which can consume a very simple WCF service, which return string to client side.

But the problem is that I can't find a way to consume the WCF service which return a `Stream` type, as the returned `Stream` is actually `StreamBody` and I don't know how to save that `StreamBody` to a local file on Delphi. Maybe it is not possible doing that in Delphi?

I am using Delphi 2007 with VS 2010 .Net 4.0
According to [this question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818391/sending-large-data-from-wcf-server-to-delphi-client), maybe using `Stream` is not such a great idea at all. And I think for documents I could return `bye[]` to client side instead, but I still like the idea of `Stream` over network instead of Array.

Comment: This is only a comment since I don't know enough about WCF; Normally the whole response of a WCF service request is sent as a single logical package; This is good and portable, but doesn't work well for very large responses (think hundreds of Mb). That's what Streaming is for, and with streaming, the whole response is not necessary sent as a whole; It's simply a more involved delivery mechanism, you need support for it on both server and client side. Since you're obviously not using WCF on both sides, use something more portable, something that delivers everything at once; Like `byte[]`

Comment: En, probably streaming document is not necessary, if too complex in some platform such as Delphi. I just want make sure it is indeed impossible or too complex in Delphi, as I am afraid don't know enough about Delphi or WCF.